# Secure authentication of client over RMI

Tags: java, security, authentication, rmi

I was thinking to authenticate users of my RMI service like this

```
interface RemoteService extends Remote { ... }
interface RemoteServiceProvider extends Remote { ... }
class RemoteServiceProviderImpl implements RemoteServiceProvider {
   RemoteService getService(String authCode) throws RemoteException {
     if (check(authCode)) return (RemoteService) UnicastRemoteObject.export(theRemoteService, 0);
     else throw ...;
   }

}
```

However, that's probably not really secure. I suspect that when the the real service is `export`ed, anybody who guesses the correct port can acquire it.

How can I do this the right way?

Comment: When you say "anybody who guessed the correct port can acquire it." what do you mean? Are you referring, they could acquire the authCode that is being passed through?

Comment: @momo he mean that anyone who guesses the remote binding of theRemoteService will be able to use it

Comment: ... in which case he would be wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks like when the the real service is exported, anybody who
>   guesses the correct port can acquire it.

No. They would also have to guess a remote object ID, and there is a system property that causes them to be generated via a secure RNG. They would also have to have the remote interface class, and they would also have to be able to construct a remote stub to the object with the correct IP:port, remote interface(s), and remote UID. Not easy. However you should certainly look into SSL with mutual authentication if you have serious security concerns, and maybe the full Jini/Secure JERI thing if you are totally and utterly serious about secure RMI. See also [this white paper](http://www.telekinesis.com.au/wipv3_6/FileDispatch?id=247566).